# How to get CVPixelBuffer handle from UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> in Swift?

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, video-toolbox

I got a decoded **AVFrame** whose format shows 160/`Videotoolbox_vld`. After googled some articles([here](https://medium.com/liveop-x-team/accelerating-h264-decoding-on-ios-with-ffmpeg-and-videotoolbox-1f000cb6c549)) and viewed the **FFmpeg** source code([here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/1ee863a7b05aaf358c43c3a788e020cc1c752c59/libavcodec/videotoolboxenc.c#L2162), and [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/036b4b0f85933f49a7094b5b568a93f68c9cd544/libavutil/hwcontext_videotoolbox.c#L109)), the `CVBuffer` handle should be at `AVFrame.data[3]`. But the `CVBuffer` I got seems invalid, any `CVPixelBufferGetXXX()` function returns 0 or nil.

If I used the `av_hwframe_transfer_data()` like the ffmpeg's [example/hw_decode.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/036b4b0f85933f49a7094b5b568a93f68c9cd544/doc/examples/hw_decode.c#L110) did, the sample can be downloaded from HW to SW buffer. Its `AVFrame.format` will be `nv12`. After converted via `sws_scale` to `bgra`, the sample can be showed on view with correct content.

I think the VideoToolbox decoded frame is OK. The way I convert `AVFrame.data[3]` to `CVBuffer` may be wrong. Just learned accessing c pointer in swift but I am not sure how to read a resource handle(CVBuffer) in a pointer correctly.

The following is how I try to extract CVBuffer from AVFrame

```
var pFrameOpt: UnsafeMutablePointer<AVFrame>? = av_frame_alloc()
avcodec_receive_frame(..., pFrameOpt)

let data3: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? = pFrameOpt?.pointee.data.3
data3?.withMemoryRebound(to: CVBuffer.self, capacity: 1) { pCvBuf in
    let fW = pFrameOpt!.pointee.width // print 3840
    let fH = pFrameOpt!.pointee.height // print 2160
    let fFmt = pFrameOpt!.pointee.format // print 160

    let cvBuf: CVBuffer = pCvBuf.pointee

    let a1 = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(cvBuf)               // print 0
    let a2 = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(cvBuf)        // print 0
    let a3 = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvBuf)                  // print 0
    let a4 = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvBuf)                 // print 0
    let a5 = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvBuf)            // print 0
    let a6 = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(cvBuf, 0)  // print 0
    let a7 = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(cvBuf, 0)        // print 0
    let a8 = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(cvBuf, 0)       // print 0
    let a9 = CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(cvBuf)             // print 0
    let a10 = CVPixelBufferIsPlanar(cvBuf)                 // print false
    let a11 = CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface(cvBuf)             // print nil
    let a12 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvBuf)           // print nil
    let a13 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(cvBuf, 0) // print nil

    let b1 = CVImageBufferGetCleanRect(cvBuf)   // print 0, 0, 0, 0
    let b2 = CVImageBufferGetColorSpace(cvBuf)  // print nil 
    let b3 = CVImageBufferGetDisplaySize(cvBuf) // print 0, 0, 0, 0
    let b4 = CVImageBufferGetEncodedSize(cvBuf) // print 0, 0, 0, 0
    let b5 = CVImageBufferIsFlipped(cvBuf)      // print false

    // bad exec
    var cvTextureOut: CVMetalTexture?
    CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, ..., cvBuf, nil, .bgra8Unorm, 3840, 2160, 0, ...) 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CVBuffer` is not a fixed size, so rebinding the memory won't work in this way. You need to do this:

```swift
Unmanaged<CVBuffer>.fromOpaque(data!).takeRetainedValue()
```

However, the bottom line is FFmpeg's VideoToolbox backend is not creating a `CVPixelBuffer` with `kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey` set to `true`. You won't be able to call `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(...)` successfully in any case.

You could consider using a `CVPixelBufferPool` with appropriate settings (including `kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey` set to `true`) and then using `VTPixelTransferSession` to quickly copy FFmpeg's pixel buffer to your own.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I wrongly cast `void*` to `CVPixelBuffer*` instead of casting `void*` directly to `CVPixelBuffer`. I cannot find a swift way to do such c style casting from pointer to numeric value. (Using `as! CVPixelBuffer` causes crash).

So I create a function for `void*` to `CVPixelBufferRef` in C code to do such casting job.

```c
// util.h
#include <CoreVideo/CVPixelBuffer.h>
CVPixelBufferRef CastToCVPixelBuffer(void* p);
```

```c
// util.c
CVPixelBufferRef CastToCVPixelBuffer(void* p)
{
    return (CVPixelBufferRef)p;
}
```

```c
// BridgeHeader.h
#include "util.h"
```

Then pass the `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` in, get **CVPixelBuffer** handle out.

```swift
let pFrameOpt: UnsafeMutablePointer<AVFrame>? = ...
let data3: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? = pFrameOpt?.pointee.data.3

let cvBuf: CVBuffer = CastToCVPixelBuffer(data3).takeUnretainedValue()

let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvBuf)   // print 3840
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvBuf) // print 2160
```

Comment: Just checked. My one-liner answer is correct and the most straightforward way to do this without needing to bring obj-c into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let cvBuf: CVBuffer = Array(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: data3, count: 3))
.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
   $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: CVBuffer.self, capacity: 1) { $0 }
}.pointee
```

or maybe even

```
let cvBuf: CVBuffer = unsafeBitcast(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: data3, count: 3), to: CVBuffer.self)
```

Comment: I had tried this and failed. All the CVPixelXX Getter function returns invalid data. I think it just converted to CVPixelBuffer* instead of CVPixelBuffer directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
    @function   CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane
    @abstract   Returns the base address of the plane at planeIndex in the PixelBuffer.
    @discussion Retrieving the base address for a PixelBuffer requires that the buffer base address be locked
                via a successful call to CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress. On OSX 10.10 and earlier, or iOS 8 and
                earlier, calling this function with a non-planar buffer will have undefined behavior.
    @param      pixelBuffer Target PixelBuffer.
    @param      planeIndex  Identifying the plane.
    @result     Base address of the plane, or NULL for non-planar CVPixelBufferRefs.
*/
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public func CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(_ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, _ planeIndex: Int) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
```

maybe you can try use CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress before use CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane